# Likely cause(s) for Word recovering large document frequently?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010, file-recovery

I have a large Word document (*.docx) that has recently started to go into Document Recovery at frequent intervals (< 30 mins) after having previously been very stable for the 3-4 years that it has been growing.

I am using Word 2010 [version 14.0.7149.5000 (32-bit)] on Windows 7 SP1 with 8Gb RAM.  I am the only editor (and viewer) of this document.

It is a document that I would really prefer not to have to split.  It has these characteristics:

- 174Mb in size
- 728 pages
- 135,000 word
- 850,000 characters
- over 200 images
- thousands of hyperlinks

I expect that this document might end up being about twice this size before it is completed.

Are there any obvious things that I could try to reduce the need for this document to enter recovery so often?

So far the document has recovered fine each time with just 10-15 minutes work lost, and needing to be repeated.

Comment: Try Saving it As a .docx (with another name even if it was already in that format), then check whether the new version also exhibits the same issue. If you still have problems try repairing Office. 64-bit Office might also help perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  It is already a *.docx, and whenever it recovers the document that is saved as a new file, but nevertheless I will try doing a more controlled Save As.  I'll keep repairing Office or switching from 32-bit to 64-bit in reserve while I test the outcome of your first suggestion, and await any other comments and answers.

Comment: The symptoms suggest three things: 1) Large complex documents are problem prone.  Try splitting it to see if the problem disappears. 2) You might be bumping up against some kind of limit; either in Word or your computer.  See if the same problem occurs on another computer.  See if the problem occurs on your computer opening only Word after a clean boot (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135?wa=wsignin1.0).  3) The document or Word could be corrupted.  Try to save or export to a different format, like .odt.  That sometimes forces a cleanup.  cont'd...

Comment: (Cont'd)  Word handles .odt natively, but you can also open the file in another application, like LibreOffice (which is free and available for Windows), to check it and see if the problem persists.  In Word, save it back as .docx and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large, complex documents have always been problematic in Word. One thing that makes the situation worse is when you include text from other Word documents that come from different authors/templates/etc. This is due to the way that Word handles certain internal structures such as bulleted and numbered lists. I've had large documents so unreliable that I resorted to creating a VBA macro that took a copy of the last saved version of the document before overwriting with the new save.

If the document does contain a composite from other locations, possibly the only way to fix it would be to start a brand new document and carefully copy/paste-as-text from the original then apply consistent style-based formatting as you go along. Of course, this can be a very major task but it is highly likely that it will fix the issue.

As well as Karan's suggestion of doing a new Save-As, you could also open the document in Open Office, save to ODT, reopen in Word and Save As docx. Be warned though that this might well have other side effects like messed up formatting. Watch the file size, if it suddenly changes by a large %, it is likely something went wrong. **Keep lots of versions!**

Comment: Since doing the Save As, I have not encountered a problem in the time frame that I was having trouble previously, so I won't assume all is fine just yet but you and the commenters have given me a number of avenues to pursue if the problem recurs.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

1. In MS Word, click Save As
2. Save As HTML - not docx
3. Close Word.
4. Reopen Word.
5. Open the HTML file in Word.
6. Save As .docx.

This process will reduce the file size and remove rogue styles. You might have to reformat some of the doc but I suspect it will crash less.

Ivan